# RedditExtractoR in R language: error-Subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

My goal is to use RedditExtractoR to crawl reddit user post.
The following is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RedditExtractoR)
user <- "a_guy828"
user_content <- get_user_content(user) # It shows error that page[[content_type]]：subscript out of bounds
user_threads<-user_content[[user]]$threads
view(user_threads)
```

When working in
`user_content <- get_user_content(user)`
I get the error message "subscript out of bounds"
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. I cannot figure out why.

But if these user(s) can be excluded, then skipping over these users while extracting the other users can help (though it does not solve the problem)

````
# create a list the extraction to save inside
users_extracted <- list() 

# Function for the extraction
get_data <- function(x) {
    get_user_content(x)
}

# This is the workhorse to bring the data in (while skipping those users with errors)
get_data2 <- possibly(get_data, otherwise = NA)


# Run the loop with your list of user names (list_of_users_names)
for(i in list_of_users_names) {
    users_extracted[i] <- get_data2(i)
}

```
````